# wp_link_query: Classic editor link popup adds custom CPT links again and again

Tags: wordpress

When I integrate my CPT into the link search of the Classic Editor, it is at first displayed correctly.

But if there are more links in the list than can be displayed at the same time (overflow) and I then scroll up and down again, the list is updated by Wordpress via Ajax and my CPT links are appended again, so that the link list becomes longer and longer.
The default Wordpress links (post, page) on the other hand do not, even though my ID and the permalink in the $results array are unique.
There is nothing more than ID, title, permalink and info in the original $results array.

How can I prevent the appending?

```
    add_filter('wp_link_query', array($this, 'wp_link_query'), 10, 2);
    [...]

    public function wp_link_query($results, $query) {
        [...]        
        $results[] = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'title' => $title,
            'permalink' => $permalink,
            'info' => $info
        );
        return $results;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I have now figured out that $query contains an offset that is increased when scrolling. Now the only question is how to handle the offset correctly, because the length of the list is extended dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the custom post type to the link query args first:

```
add_filter('wp_link_query_args', array($this, 'wp_link_query_args'), 10, 1);
[...]
public function wp_link_query_args($query) {
   $query['post_type'][] = 'my_cpt';
   return $query;
}
´´´´
But you have to still use the 'wp_link_query' filter to add the "info" of the link popup table. Otherwise Wordpress outputs "Null" for the custom post type.
```